# Codechef: The Chefora Spell

Tags: java, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

This is the question currently I am trying to solve of [codechef](https://www.codechef.com/JULY21C/problems/CHEFORA) and I am able to get the given test cases result but I am getting Time Limit Exceeded when I am trying to submit. Please let me know what can i do in my code given below to make it more optimized.

> Chef and his friend Bharat have decided to play the game "The Chefora
> Spell".
>
> In the game, a positive integer \$N\$ (in decimal system) is considered a
> "Chefora" if the number of digits \$d\$ is **odd** and it satisfies the
> equation
>
> \$N=\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{d−1} N_{i} ⋅10^i\$,
>
> where \$N_i+\$ is the \$i\$-th digit of \$N\$ from the
> left in 0-based indexing.
>
> Let \$A_i\$ denote the i-th **smallest** Chefora number.
>
> They'll ask each other \$Q\$ questions, where each question contains two
> integers \$L\$ and \$R\$. The opponent then has to answer with
>
> \$(\displaystyle \prod _{i=L+1}^{R} (A_{L})^{ A_{i}})mod 10^{9}+7.\$
>
> Bharat has answered all the questions right,
> and now it is Chef's turn. But since Chef fears that he could get some
> questions wrong, you have come to his rescue!
>
> ### Input
>
> The first line contains an integer \$Q\$ - the number of questions
> Bharat asks. Each of the next \$Q\$ lines contains two integers \$L\$ and \$R\$.
>
> ### Output
>
> Print \$Q\$ integers - the answers to the questions on separate
> lines.
>
> ### Constraints
>
> \$1≤Q≤10^5\$
>
> \$1≤L<R≤10^5\$
>
> ### Subtasks
>
> #### Subtask #1 (30 points):
>
> \$1≤Q≤5⋅10^3\$
>
> \$1≤L<R≤5⋅10^3\$
>
> #### Subtask #2 (70 points):
>
> Original constraints
>
> ### Sample Input
>
> ```
> 2
> 1 2
> 9 11
> ```
>
> ### Sample Output
>
> ```
> 1 
> 541416750
> ```

### Code

```java
 

    import java.util.*;
    import java.lang.*;
    import java.io.*;

    class Codechef
    {   
        public static class FastReader{
            BufferedReader br;
            StringTokenizer st;
            public FastReader(){
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            }
            String next(){
                while(st == null || !st.hasMoreElements()){
                   try{
                    st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
                }catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println(e);
                } 
                }
                return st.nextToken();
            }
            public long nextLong(){
               return Long.parseLong(next());
            }
        }
        public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
        {
            // your code goes here
            
            FastReader fr = new FastReader();
            long Q = fr.nextLong();
            while(Q-->0){
                long num = 0;long sol = 0;
                long L = fr.nextLong();
                long R = fr.nextLong();
                long temp = 0;
                int numDigits = countDigit(L);
                if((numDigits &1) != 0){
                num = calChefora(L);
                for(long i = L+1 ; i <= R ; i++){
                     temp = temp + calChefora(i);
                }
                sol = modPow(num , temp) ;
               System.out.println(sol);
            }
            }
            
        }
        
        static int countDigit(long n)
        {
            return (int)Math.floor(Math.log10(n) + 1);
        }
        static long calChefora(long num){
            String temp = Long.toString(num);
            if(num%10 == num)return num;
             num = num / 10;
             long reversed = 0;
             while(num!=0){
                reversed = reversed * 10 +  num % 10;
                num /= 10;
             }
             temp = temp + reversed;
             long sol = Long.parseLong(temp); 
            return sol;
            
            
        }
        
         static long modPow(long var, long num) {
        long m = 1;long M = 1000000007;
        while (num > 0) {
            m = (m * var) % M;
            --num;
        }
        return m;
    }
    }
```

**Modified Code**

```
class CHEFORA
{

    public static class FastReader{
        BufferedReader br;
        StringTokenizer st;
        public FastReader(){
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        }
        String next(){
            while(st == null || !st.hasMoreElements()){
                try{
                    st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
                }catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
            }
            return st.nextToken();
        }
        public long nextLong(){
            return Long.parseLong(next());
        }
        public int nextInt(){
            return Integer.parseInt(next());
        }
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        // your code goes here

        FastReader fr = new FastReader();
        int Q = fr.nextInt();
        ArrayList<Long> arrL = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList<Long> arrR = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList<Long> chefora = new ArrayList();

        for(int i = 0 ; i < Q ; i++){

            long L = fr.nextLong();
            long R = fr.nextLong();
            arrL.add(L); arrR.add(R);

        }
        for(long i = Collections.min(arrL) ; i <= Collections.max(arrR) ; i++){
            long temp = 0;
            temp = temp + calChefora(i);
            chefora.add(temp);
        }
        for(int i = 0 ; i < Q ; i++){
            long num = 0;long sol = 0;
            int numDigits = countDigit(arrL.get(i));

            if((numDigits &1) != 0) {
                long temp = 0;
                num = calChefora(arrL.get(i));
                int indexL = chefora.indexOf(num);
                indexL +=1;
                long diff = arrR.get(i) - arrL.get(i);

                while(diff-->0){
                    temp = temp + chefora.get(indexL);
                    indexL++;
                }

                sol = modPow(num, temp);
            }
            System.out.println(sol);
        }
    }

    static int countDigit(long n)
    {
        return (int)Math.floor(Math.log10(n) + 1);
    }
    static long calChefora(long num){
        if(num%10 == num)return num;
        String input =  String.valueOf(num);
        StringBuilder input1 = new StringBuilder();
        input1.append(input);
        input1.reverse();
        String tsol = input;
        for(int i = 1 ; i < input1.length() ;i++ ){
            tsol = tsol  + input1.charAt(i);
        }
        long sol = Long.parseLong(tsol);
       return sol;

    }
    static long modPow(long x, long y)
    {
        long M = 1000000007;
        long res = 1;

        x = x % M;

        if (x == 0)
            return 0;

        while (y > 0)
        {

            if ((y & 1) != 0)
                res = (res * x) % M;

            y = y >> 1; // y = y/2
            x = (x * x) % M;
        }
        return res;
    }

}
```

Comment: Check this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/modular-exponentiation-power-in-modular-arithmetic/

Comment: I tried this but now I am getting WA(Wrong Answer) while submitting but for the given test cases its showing correct answer. I have Added the **Modified Code** in the Question

Answer (score 1):

First of all, kudos for figuring out that \$\displaystyle \prod _{i=L+1}^{R} (A_{L})^{ A_{i}} = A_L^{\sum_{i = L+1}^R A_i}\$.

But - you've stopped too early. The next step is to realize that

\$\displaystyle \sum_{i = L+1}^R A_i = \sum_{i = 0}^R A_i - \sum_{i = 0}^L A_i\$

which hints that you need to deal with partial sums of \$A_i\$. This way you don't have to recompute the same Chefora numbers over and over again (which you do).

That said, `calChefora` seems suboptimal. A simple reversal of `temp` avoids all those modulos, divisions and multiplications.

As noted in comments, exponentiation by squaring is much faster than a naive one. Also, exponentiating modulo prime hints that [Fermat's Little](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) may help.

Finally, I failed to understand the `(numDigits & 1) != 0` test. Why parity of digits in `L` is important?

Comment: In the Question its stated that the digits should be of odd length thats why ```(numDigits & 1) != 0``` . Also i have tried changing my code and now I am first taking all the values of ```L``` and ```M``` and then I am calculating the chefora numbers from the least ```L``` to max ```M``` so that I dont have to calculate the chefora number again and again and thus reducing my time complexity but still I am getting TLE(Time limit Exceeded when submitting). Also for calculating ```modPow``` I have used bit manipulation instead of the regular calculation but still nothing.

Comment: I have added the same in the Question under **Modified Code**